# Make query not respond to changes made to cache by other queries for Apollo Client in React

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have two queries: GetNotesToApprove and GetNoteHistory. The first gets notes that the user can edit and should approve(finalize). The second gets a list of all the notes.

Both of the queries return entities of type `Note`. This means that if I apply a filter to the `GetNoteHistory` query, it will affect the `Note` returned by `GetNotesToApprove`. For example in the picture below you can see that I have applied a filter that I only want to show notefields of type 1 and 2 in my Note history. This means that I loose the inputs of all other types in my Note editor that uses result from `GetNotesToApprove` query.

**So my question is, is it possible to isolate the result from `GetNotesToApprove` so that they are not responding to changes to `Notes` in the note history?
E.g caching the response as a whole instead of normalizing it or something?**

E.g:

[image]

Comment: Please show your code. Are you filtering on the client or on the server?

Comment: If you use field arguments for that, those should already be stored independently in the cache - but you can use the `keyArgs` type policy to tweak this further: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/key-args/